# Agendador do Azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, agendamento

Alguém sabe se consigo fazer um simples programa console, que faça alguns insert em SQL e coloca-lo para rodar no agendador do Azure? (seja aquele gratuito ou aquele pago https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/scheduler/)

Vejo alguns problemas ao rodar no agendador ao invés do VM clássico:

- Seria possível eu configurar performance? pois esse programa só roda bem em VM com 4 núcleos ou mais(VM A3, ou D2 no azure)
- Existe como eu controlar a banda ou algum limite? dependendo do dia, ele pode ter um consumo de 5gb de download!

Ele é executado diariamente.

Resumindo:

> É uma boa opção programas complexos rodar no agendamento (web job) ou
>   melhor as VM classicas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> É uma boa opção programas complexos rodar no agendamento (web job) ou melhor as VM classicas?

**Sim**, é uma boa opção utilizar PaaS - Platform as a Service - para rodar programas complexos. Especialmente se não houver necessidade de micro configurações na infra estrutura.

Eu recomendaria apenas usar VM se houver a real necessidade de realizar alguma configuração no servidor de hospedagem onde uma plataforma de hospedagem não te permita.

Eu sempre penso em segregação de responsabilidades quando me perguntam sobre usar uma plataforma, ou configurar uma VM. Não é de responsabilidade do desenvolvedor a manutenção do ambiente no qual a aplicação será hospedada. Ele é responsavel apenas pela aplicação em si. Portanto, deixamos essa responsabilidade para o Azure, apenas provisione o serviço e o cosuma, que é onde haverá valor na sua solução.

[image: Cenários comuns do Azure Functions]

Usando [Azure Agendador](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/scheduler/) não é possivel, por ele apenas [gerencia trabalhos tipo HTTP](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/scheduler/scheduler-concepts-terms#a-namejob-typesatipos-de-trabalho).

Para fazer o que vc precisa, o ideal é usar [Azure Funções](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/functions/). Com ele você sequer precisa compilar um programa - até pode também, sem problemas - você apenas [hospeda o trecho de código](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview#a-namefeaturesarecursos) que precisa que seja executado - seja ele C#, F#, Node.js, Python, PHP, batch, bash ou qualquer executável.

Ele permite que você o configure orientado à um [TimeTrigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview#a-namewhat-can-i-do-with-functionsao-que-posso-fazer-com-o-functions), assim ele será executado peridicamente, de acordo com o que você definir. Veja aqui esse [exemplo de como criar um processamento de evento no Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-an-event-processing-function).

Veja aqui como [criar sua primeira Função no Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function).

**UPDATE**

Você pode limitar o consumo de recursos usando um [Plano de Serviço](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#escolher-um-plano-de-servi%C3%A7o), ou pagar apenas pelo o que seu script irá consumir - idependente de limitação de cores ou memória - usando um [Plano de Serviço Dinâmico](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#plano-de-servi%C3%A7o-din%C3%A2mico).

Veja aqui [como dimensionar seu plano de consumo do Azure Function](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Comment: e eu posso falar o quanto de recurso quero utilizar? pois imaginando que esse script hj consome vários cores e muita memória ram das VMs